# ADO application compiled in Windows 7 runs in Windows 7 does not run in Windows XP, msado15.dll

Tags: c++, operating-system, database-connection, ado

I have a program that uses the msado15.dll to connect to a database. The program runs just fine on my Windows 7 machine, but most (if not all) of the end users are running Windows XP, where it does not work. I have determined that the error is in opening the database, but there seems to be no error message, so I'm not sure what is going wrong. Here is the code I that have written, as well as the call to open the database:

Database.h:

```
#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" \
rename("EOF","adoEOF")

typedef ADODB::_RecordsetPtr RecPtr;
typedef ADODB::_ConnectionPtr CnnPtr;

struct Database {
    CnnPtr m_Cnn;
    Database();
    ~Database();
    bool Open(const char* CnnStr, const char* UserName, const char* Pwd);
    RecPtr Execute(const char* CmdStr);
    bool Close();
};
```

Database.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Database.h"
#include "ErrorDlg.h"

using namespace ADODB;

Database::Database()
{
    m_Cnn = NULL;
}

bool Database::Open(const char *CnnStr, const char *UserName, const char *Pwd)
{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT hr;
    try {
        hr = m_Cnn.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
        m_Cnn->Open(CnnStr, UserName, Pwd, adConnectUnspecified);
    }
    catch (_com_error &e) {
        CErrorDlg dlg; // makes a window that shows info aobut an error
        // the following pops up on XP when you start the .exe file and attempt to connect
        dlg.DoError(_T("Error opening database.")); //dlg.DoError(e.ErrorMessage()) gives me a blank message
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

RecPtr Database::Execute(const char *CmdStr)
{
    try {
        if (m_Cnn == NULL)
            return NULL;
        return m_Cnn->Execute(CmdStr, NULL, 1);
    }
    catch (_com_error &e) {
        CErrorDlg dlg;

        dlg.DoError(_T("Error executing database command."));
        return NULL;
    }
}

bool Database::Close()
{
    if (m_Cnn == NULL)
        return 0;

    try {
        m_Cnn->Close();
        m_Cnn = NULL;
    }
    catch (_com_error &e) {
        CErrorDlg dlg;

        dlg.DoError(_T("Error closing database"));
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

Database::~Database()
{
    try {
        if (m_Cnn) {
            m_Cnn->Close();
            m_Cnn = NULL;
        }
    }
    catch (_com_error &e) {
        CErrorDlg dlg;

        dlg.DoError(_T("Error deconstructing database"));
    }
}
```

Database is opened like this:

```
m_db.Open("driver={SQL Server};server=myServer;database=myDatabase","myUser","myPwd")
```

where `m_db` is a `Database`. I have also tried `""` for both user and pwd above, and that gives me the same result: works on 7, but not XP.

Why would this work properly on Windows 7, but not Windows XP? And what should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. See the bolded section for my exact solution, although this may also solve others.

(Taken from [this website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983246))

> Notes
>
> •Consider the scenario where you are a C++ developer, and you include the following line of code in the application:
>
> #import msado15.dll
>
> Consider the scenario that you are not using MSJRO, and you recompile the application on Windows Vista, on Windows Server 2008, or on later versions of Windows. The compiled application must run in Windows Vista, in Windows Server 2008, or in later versions of Windows. In this scenario, you must change #import msado15.dll to the following:
>
> #import msado60.tlb
>
> Consider the scenario that you are using MSJRO, and you recompile an application that must run in Windows Vista, in Windows Server 2008, or in a later version of Windows. In this scenario, you must change #import msado15.dll to the following:
>
> #import msado28.tlb
>
> **Consider the scenario that you recompile your application on Windows XP or on Windows Server 2003. Or, the recompiled application must run in Windows XP or in Windows Server 2003. In this scenario, you must change #import msado15.dll to the following:**
>
> **#import msado28.tlb**

Comment: I am using the following #import string `#import <C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado28.tlb> no_namespace rename("EOF", "adoEOF")`

Comment: Also this Microsoft KB 2640696 is more explicit about the problem I saw, [An ADO-based application that is compiled in Windows 7 SP1 or in Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 does not run in earlier versions of Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640696)